# Изменить адреса и данные для авторизации в web тестах Visual Studio 2015

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

Есть набор web тестов в Visual Studio Ultimate 2015. Изменились адреса подключений и данные для авторизации(Логин и пароль). Как изменить эти данные для каждого теста?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для смены логина и пароля надо перейти на нужный WebTest и нажать кнопку `Set Creedentails`.
[image: Изменение логина и пароля]
Для смены сервера надо перейти на нужный WebTest и нажать кнопку `Parametrize Web Services`
[image: Изменение сервера для подключения]